# Open a pdf file using javax.ws and angular

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, pdf

I am trying to open a PDF file, saved in the server, using a Java Restful service and angularjs.
My code for the service in Java is:

```
@GET
@Path("/getPDF")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response getPDF() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("/path/to/file.pdf");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    long contentLength = file.length();
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok((Object) fileInputStream);
    responseBuilder.type("application/pdf");
    responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=file.pdf");
    responseBuilder.header("Content-Length", contentLength);
    responseBuilder.header("charset", "utf-8");
    return responseBuilder.build();
}
```

Once the Response is returned I handle the request with angularjs:

```
MyJavaService.getPDF().success(function(data){
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $window.open(fileURL);
});
```

The result is that a new window opens, with the same number of pages like the PDF file (correct), but the content is not displayed and all the pages are white (not correct).

Does anyone have any clue of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a $http.get() call.

You probably having something along the lines of:

```
$http.get(<URL>, {params: <stuff>})
```

You need to tell angular that the responseType is an arrayBuffer like so:

```
$http.get(<URL>, {responseType: 'arraybuffer', params: <stuff>})
```

Don't hesitate to tell me my assumptions are incorrect.

p.s.: try to avoid using .success() and instead use .then(). The former is deprecated 1.4+ and completely removed in 1.6+